# Android ImageView Showing Blurry Images in Gallery

Tags: android, imageview, blurry

my I have good quality images in my phone image gallery. When I try to add these files to ImageView it shows very blurry

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#CCC"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Why it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your width and height to `wrap_content`, like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#CCC"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Or if you need to keep your ImageView size, try using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to fit your image inside ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

remove height : 250dp and make it wrap_content and that's it